# OR operator in Mongo 'update' $criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want to check for an existing record by matching either title or url fields. If either one matches, update that record. Otherwise, insert.

How do write the following properly (using Mongoid in Ruby):

```
articles.update(
{ **:title => story.title OR :url => story.url** },
{ :title => story.title, :url => story.url, :source => story.source, :last_updated => Time.now },
{ :upsert => true } )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do the request and update it like :

'''
articles.any_of({:title => xxx}, {:url => yyyy}).update( :foo => 'bar')
'''